# optimize a promise scenario in bluebird in my Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, promise, bluebird

I was wondering how to optimize the below code and remove global variables `conngbl` and `stgbl`.Also this code fails to insert some records during perf testing. Is this because i fail to catch some errors?  Please help me find those scenarios.

The code is

```
     var conngbl;
            var stgbl;
            db.newConnection()
                .then(conn => {

                    conngbl = conn;
                    conn.setAutoCommit(false)
                    return conn.createStatement()
                })
                .then(st => {
                    stgbl=st;
                    st.setQueryTimeout(300);
                    // queryStack.map(function(query) {
                        // st.addBatch(query);
                    // })
                    return Promise.map(queryStack,function(query){
                        return st.addBatch(query)
                    })
                })
                .then(()=>{

                    return stgbl.executeBatch();
                })
                .then(rowsUpdated => {

                    return console.log('rows update:', rowsUpdated.length);
                })
                .then(() => {

                    if (conngbl) {

                        return conngbl.commit();
                    }else{
                        logger.info("id", req.id,"connection object is null. Couldn't commit");
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .then((isNull) =>{
                    if(!isNull){

                        return conngbl.close();
                    }else{

                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .then((isNull)=>{
                    if(!isNull){
                        logger.info("id", req.id,"connection close successful")
                    }else{
                        logger.info("id", req.id,"connection close NOT successful")
                    }
                    return callback(null)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("Error occured during insertToDb", error)
                    })
```

Comment: You could at least format the code reasonably when asking people for help.

Comment: Fundamentally: You don't want one long chain, you want nesting.

Comment: Sorry about that. i have done my best editing it from my mobile.

Comment: @crowder. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by nesting. I am looking for excpetion scenarios and possibility of missing those .

Comment: Sorry TJ, but the other TJ's criticism still stands: your code is pretty awful to parse as it's currently entered. Try editing it from a laptop so it's a bit more legible. Also, posting the output of your perf step would help analyze what you consider the 'problems' here.